# join 3 table columns and describe in datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I need a sql query which retrieves information from different tables and describe them in a datagrid. These are my tables

**tablename: register**

```
-reg_id(PK)
-date
-timebegin
-begin_photo_id
-timeend
-end_photo_id
-pupils_id
```

**tablename: pupils**

```
-pupils_id(PK)
-name
-surname
-mid_name
-group_id
```

**tablename: photos**

```
-photo_id(PK)
-photo
```

Query meaning: `Select date, timebegin, timeend from register; Select photo from photos where photo_id=begin_photo_if and photo_id=end_photo_id` which is related to register table; `Select concat(name, surname, mid_name) as fullname from pupils pupils.pupils_id=register.pupils_id`. That means instead `register.pupils_id` must be fullname which is taken from pupils. And last condition is show them where group_id=combobox.selectedvalue.

Result column names should be:

```
-fullname
-date
-timebegin
-photo
-timeend
-photo


where group_id=combobox_value
```

So I need some help.

Comment: Some help with what exactly?  You expecting someone to write it for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
fullname = concat(p.name, p.surname, p.mid_name),
r.date,
r.timebegin,
begin_photo = pbegin.photo,
r.timeend,
end_photo = pend.photo
from register r
left join pupils p on p.pupils_id = r.pupils_id
left join photos pbegin on pbegin.photo_id = r.begin_photo_id
left join photos pend on pend.photo_id = r.end_photo_id
where p.group_id = combobox_value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked